# How can I define a function with default parameter values and optional parameters in Python?

Tags: python

I want to define a function to which the input parameters can be omitted or have a default value.

I have this function:

```
def nearxy(x,y,x0,y0,z):
   distance=[]
   for i in range(0,len(x)):   
   distance.append(abs(math.sqrt((x[i]-x0)**2+(y[i]-y0)**2)))
   ...
   return min(distance)
```

I want make `x0` and `y0` have a default value, and make `z` optional if I don't have a `z` value.

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give default values to x0,y0 like this and if z is optional  also :

```
def nearxy(x,y,x0=0,y0=0,z=None):
   distance=[]
   for i in range(0,len(x)):   
   distance.append(abs(math.sqrt((x[i]-x0)**2+(y[i]-y0)**2)))
   if z is not None:
        blah blah
   return min(distance)
```

call :

```
nearxy(1,2)
```

if you want only toassign z :

```
 nearxy(1,2,z=3)
```

....

hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

You can't make function arguments optional in Python, but you can give them default values. So:

```
def nearxy(x, y, x0=0, y0=0, z=None):
    ...
```

That makes `x0` and `y0` have default values of `0`, and `z` have a default value of `None`.

Assuming `None` makes no sense as an actual value for `z`, you can then add logic in the function to do something with `z` only if it's not `None`.

Comment: Having `None` as a default argument makes sense cause the default argument object is persistent between calls of the function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 4):

```
def nearxy(x, y, x0 = 0, y0 = 0, z = None):
   ...
```

Check if `z` is `None` to see if it has been omitted.

Answer (score 2):

To specify a default value, define the parameter with a '=' and then the value.

An argument where a default value is specified *is* an optional argument.

For example, if you wanted `x0`,`y0`, and `z` to have default values of 1,2,3:

```
def nearxy(x,y,x0=1,y0=2,z=3):
   distance=[]
   for i in range(0,len(x)):   
       distance.append(abs(math.sqrt((x[i]-x0)**2+(y[i]-y0)**2)))
   ...
   return min(distance)
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values for more.